# Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1 Generate Signed Bundle / APK wizard does not open

Tags: android-studio

I have upgraded to `Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1`, and noticed that after a number of successful builds on my stagingRelease apk the `Generate Signed Bundle / APK` wizard does not open

this the version of android studio i am using

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8139111, built on February 1, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 12
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true, debugger.watches.in.variables=false
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.6.10-release-923-AS7442.40)
```

none of the actions i have tried have rectified this issue

i have tried closing and reopening android studio

invalidating caches and restarting

what is the solution to this issue?